# is this code not allowing me to collapse because it is erronous?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Okay - I've been working on some asp.net applications, and one of the habits I learned is to make sure that all my td's and tr's collapse which tells me that everything is correct.

So every single collapsable item, collapses properly with one exception. I have spent some time trying to figure out what the heck the issue could be but I just can't see it.

Everything looks proper when I launch my form, i'm just worried that if user launches it it might show something incorrectly.

Any ideas?

[image]

The red bracket shows where I am unable to collapse. Every other td and tr is collapsable within that particular table, with that one exception.

I got rid of the style="padding-Left:20px" and instead used spaces, like this..

```
<tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;proceeding under which I was mandated into treatment
    </td>
</tr>
```

Still the same problem - won't let me collapse TR

Comment: The editor just does that sometimes. Just ignore it, your code looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because this td has a text node on a line by itself.  If you were to put that text in a `<span>` tag it would then collapse.  Most editors seem to behave that way.  Not sure why.  But it is just one reason why you shouldn't use collapsing to check code validity.  Its not bad for a quick check, but obviously has limitations.